# Erro de cors acessar Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

Pessoal estou tentando acessar um serviço da wikipedia com JQ, mas esta em retornando erro de cors, alguém poderia me ajudar com um código para acessar esse serviço corretamente.

Url: https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=google

erro

Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=google. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Comment: insere o erro para facilitar a ajuda.

Comment: coloquei mas é este Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=google. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma proteção que os navegadores possuem, evitando que um cliente em outro endereço faça uma requisição direto em algum site, salvo o caso em que ele autorize o tráfego externo. Nessas situações, vale a pena tentar usar o JSONP. Em uma requisição AJAX com Jquery fica assim:

```js
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=google",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
 
request.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log(msg)
});
 
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  console.log(jqXHR, textStatus)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Caramba que coisa :( existe algum tipo de serviço API para fazer isso ? eu usava um mas parou de funcionar.

Comment: Não que eu conheça. Você teria que realmente construir uma API... Uma saída que eu utilizo nos meus projetos é usar as Cloud Functions do Firebase.

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado.

Comment: Tirei um tempinho para ver a API da Wikipedia, e consegui puxar no client. Basta usar `jsonp`. Você está fazendo a requisição com ajax do jquery? Se estiver, coloque `dataType: 'jsonp'`. Aqui funcionou normalmente

Comment: @JoãoPedroHenrique Eu estava testando justamente isso agora, pode colocar como resposta porque funciona mesmo.

Comment: Feito, Leandro. Valeu pelo toque ;)

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado amigo :D top